# Persist the value set for an env variable on the shell after the go program exits

Tags: go

Is there a way i can set an Environment variable on my shell and have it persist after the go program exits ? I tried the following

```
bash-3.2$ export WHAT=am
bash-3.2$ echo $WHAT
am

bash-3.2$ go build tt.go 
bash-3.2$ ./tt
am
is your name
bash-3.2$ echo $WHAT
am
bash-3.2$
```

The code was :

```
package main`
import (
        "fmt"
       "os"`
)

func main() {
fmt.Println(os.Getenv("WHAT"))
os.Setenv("WHAT", "is your name")
fmt.Println(os.Getenv("WHAT"))
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

No, environment variables can only be passed down, not up. You're trying to do the latter.

Your process tree:

```
`--- shell
          `--- go program
          |
          `--- other program
```

The go program would have to pass the environment variable up to the shell so that the other program can access it.

What you can do is what programs like `ssh-agent` do: return a string that can be interpreted as setting a environment variable which can then be evaluated by the shell.

For example:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("WHAT='is your name'")
}
```

Running it will give you:

```
$ ./goprogram
WHAT='is your name'
```

Evaluating the printed string will give you the desired effect:

```
$ eval `./goprogram`
$ echo $WHAT
is your name
```

Comment: Ok. I See . Is there any way for me to then spawn a shell process within the go program, set the variables in that, run whatever function on that and then exit that process once I'm done ? I have some tests that are dependent on some environment variables being set. However the rest of the tests in my project need different values for those variables. Hence I'm trying to figure out how best to handle this situation so that I can still run go test ./... and not have any test fail.

Comment: Sure. See the `os/exec` package and use `/bin/sh -c '<shell command>'`.

Comment: @kbinstance For the sake of all the other questions you asked, please mark answers that helped you solve your question as accepted (check mark below the vote buttons of the answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No.

A process has a copy of its parent's environment and can't write to the parent environment.

Comment: @memo's answer is more detailed than mine, accept his.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are strictly correct, however you are free to execute your golang code to populate arbitrary values to environment variables into an output file your go creates then back in the parent environment from which you executed that go binary then source the go's output file to have available env variables calculated from inside your go code ... this could be your go code write_to_file.go

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {

    d1 := []byte("export whodunit=calculated_in_golang\n")
    if err := ioutil.WriteFile("/tmp/cool_file", d1, 0644); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

now compile above write_to_file.go into binary `write_to_file` ... here is a bash script which can act as the parent to execute above binary

```
#!/bin/bash

whodunit=aaa

if [[ -z $whodunit ]]; then

    echo variable whodunit has no value
else

    echo variable whodunit has value $whodunit
fi

./write_to_file # <-- execute golang binary here which populates an exported var in output file /tmp/cool_file

curr_cool=/tmp/cool_file

if [[ -f $curr_cool ]]; then # if file exists

    source /tmp/cool_file # shell distinguishes sourcing shell from executing, sourcing does not cut a subshell it happens in parent env
fi

if [[ -z $whodunit ]]; then

    echo variable whodunit still has no value 
else

    echo variable whodunit finally has value $whodunit
fi
```

here is the output from executing above shell script

```
variable whodunit has value aaa
variable whodunit finally has value calculated_in_golang
```